# Viewing bytecode in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a problem with my Android Studio Show byte code is disabled. How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Seeing Kotlin ByteCode

Open that particular file by double clicking it .. Once in that file click `Ctrl-Shift-A` to open the global action search.

Search For Kotlin ByteCode and click enter.
You'll be able to see the ByteCode in a pane to the left

Ref:[Medium Article on Seeing Java Equivalent of Kotlin File](https://medium.com/@mydogtom/tip-how-to-show-java-equivalent-for-kotlin-code-f7c81d76fa8)

2. See Dalvik Bytecode

Create an APK of your file and then Build-> Analyze APK and analyse that apk. Open `classes.dex`. Right click on the file you want to see and then select `Show ByteCode`